# Delphi Xe2: WH_KEYBOARD won't return left-right virtual key codes

Tags: delphi, hook, virtual-keyboard

I'm trying to create a DLL in order to (globally) hook key-strokes and send them to my application. Everything's working fine (hooking, messaging etc). The only problem i have is that i can't manage to return the codes of left-right virtual keys (VK_LSHIFT, VK_RSHIFT, VK_LCONTROL and so on).

I've spent few hours reading msdn about KeyboardProc, VkKeyScan, MapVirtualKey etc.. without being able to make a solution. Here's my code:

```
function HookCallBack(Code: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LongInt; stdcall;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if (Code < HC_ACTION) then Exit;
  if (Code = HC_NOREMOVE) then Result := CallNextHookEx(Keyboard, Code, wParam, lParam);
  if (Code = HC_ACTION) then begin
    PostMessage(Reciever, WM_USER + 1, wParam, lParam);
    Result := CallNextHookEx(Keyboard, Code, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;
```

I believe it has to do something with `LParam` according to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Keystroke_Message_Flags) but i'm still not able to figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: After spending many hours on this problem, i found out that `LParamHi` returns codes similar to [linux keycode table](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlkeycodes.html) which is able to send different codes of each of those keys. For example LSHIFT = 42, RSHIFT = 54, LCTRL = 29, RCTRL = 29+256(?) etc. I'm now trying to figure out these small details.

Answer (score 2):

Shift, Alt, Ctrl - isn't a keys. It's a key modifiers, these keys doesn't have own real key code. You can really detect they, only if pressed other non-modifer key.

See, TWinControl implementation for understanding, how to detect these keys:

```
function TWinControl.DoKeyDown(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean;
var
  ShiftState: TShiftState;
  Form, FormParent: TCustomForm;
  LCharCode: Word;
begin
 ...
  with Message do
  begin
    ShiftState := KeyDataToShiftState(KeyData); //see this method.
    if not (csNoStdEvents in ControlStyle) then
    begin
      LCharCode := CharCode;
      KeyDown(LCharCode, ShiftState);
      CharCode := LCharCode;
      if LCharCode = 0 then Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: I wish i could vote up for you but it says i need 15 reputation :) Anyway, i thought that they had their own code (from 0xA0 to 0xA5) so i was trying to capture those. But yeah, no matter what, they always return 0x10 (shift), 0x11 (ctrl), 0x12 (alt). Thank you for your reply :)